# sqlalchemy INSERT from SELECT

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a trouble. 
The INSERT from SELECT construction compiles, but not performed. There aren't any error. If look to the log file, you won't SQL like ISERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ....

This is is my code:

```
    DBSession.query(ProductMediaGalleryArchive)\
        .filter(ProductMediaGalleryArchive.product_id.in_(pack))\
        .delete(synchronize_session=False)

    query = DBSession.query(
            ProductMediaGallery.code,
            ProductMediaGallery.filename,
            ProductMediaGallery.mimetype,
            ProductMediaGallery.sha1hash,
            ProductMediaGallery.position,
            ProductMediaGallery.excluded,
            ProductMediaGallery.created,
            ProductMediaGallery.updated,
            ProductMediaGallery.id,
            ProductMediaGallery.is_rollover,
            Product.code.label('product_code'),
        ).join((Product, Product.id==ProductMediaGallery.product_id))\
        .filter(ProductMediaGallery.product_id.in_(pack))

    insert(ProductMediaGalleryArchive).from_select(
        (
            ProductMediaGalleryArchive.code,
            ProductMediaGalleryArchive.filename,
            ProductMediaGalleryArchive.mimetype,
            ProductMediaGalleryArchive.sha1hash,
            ProductMediaGalleryArchive.position,
            ProductMediaGalleryArchive.excluded,
            ProductMediaGalleryArchive.created,
            ProductMediaGalleryArchive.updated,
            ProductMediaGalleryArchive.id,
            ProductMediaGalleryArchive.is_rollover,
            ProductMediaGalleryArchive.product_code
        ),
        query
    )
```

Anybody know why doesn't performed it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer is closed. I've missed the `execute` statement.
insert().from_select() generates only a text, SQL query.
It should be used as follows:

```
session.execute(insert(...).from_select(...)
```